# Как подключить библиотеку luabridge?

Tags: c++, lua

Хотел подключить библиотеку [luabridge](https://github.com/vinniefalco/LuaBridge) которая позволяет подключить lua скрипты к c++, но ничего не получилось вылезли ошибки которые я даже не знаю как исправить

[image: Ошибки]

[image: C/C++/ОБЩИЕ]

[image: Код]

[image: Исходники]

[image: Компоновщик/Общие]

[image: Компоновщик/Ввод]

[image: Стандарты]

Код:

```
#include <LuaBridge.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
extern "C" {
# include "lua.h"
# include "lauxlib.h"
# include "lualib.h"
}
 
using namespace luabridge;
int main() {
    lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_dofile(L, "script.lua");
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
    LuaRef s = getGlobal(L, "testString");
    LuaRef n = getGlobal(L, "number");
    std::string luaString = s.cast<std::string>();
    int answer = n.cast<int>();
    std::cout << luaString << std::endl;
    std::cout << "And here's our number:" << answer << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ко всем ошибкам вы добавили свою - выплеснули все в виде картинок, которые никто не будет смотреть... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Вы предлагаете вместо картинок вставить все 20 ошибок? И все, что я выставил в настройках проекта?

Comment: Ну, ждите ответа...

Comment: *"Вы предлагаете вместо картинок вставить все 20 ошибок? И все, что я выставил в настройках проекта? "* - именно так. Настройки проекта можно скопипастить со страницы с командной строкой

Comment: О Господи всего добавил 7 фотографии такая реакция как будто вас насильно заставляют смотреть 50 фотографий с плохим качеством. Не надо не смотрите и не отвечайте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Директивы `#include` идут в неправильном порядке, о чём сообщает ошибка

> Lua headers must be included prior to LuaBridge ones

Пример правильной последовательности можно посмотреть в примерах использования LuaBridge (например, [здесь](https://github.com/shybovycha/lua-bridge-sample/blob/master/1-call-lua-function-from-cpp/main.cpp))

Comment: Здраствуйте спасибо помогло, но для того что-бы это заработало пришлось поменять версию LuaBridge 2 на LuaBridge 3.